# I want to trigger 1 request of Loop-1 on every 10 Threads in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is like,
**I want to trigger 1 request of loop when 10 threads executed. How do I do that?**
I used below groovy but it didn't worked. It didn't triggers my request.

```
${__groovy(((vars.get('__jm__Thread Group__idx') as int + 1) % 10) == 0,)}
```

Can anyone please tell how do I get Thread group counts and put it in condition?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could you please describe in details how exactly this "did not worked"?

Your setup assumes that the request under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) will be executed each 10th iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

I can think of the following situations:

1. The request is not executed at all. If this is the case - add more iterations to the Thread Group so the number will be 10 or more
2. The request is being executed but you don't see other requests. If this is the case add another [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) outside the If Controller and you will see them

[image]

Comment: when I use Loop count in thread group it works fine but I don't want to use that loop. I want Number of Threads: 10, RampUp: 1 and LoopCount:1. and in IF loop it will trigger 1 request. Like this.

Comment: If you want to run a request with each 10 user then you need to amend your [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function in the If Controller to look like `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() % 10 == 0,)}`. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) to learn more about what do these `ctx` and `vars` guys mean